# Does "DataContext = new ..." instantiate an accessible object?

Tags: wpf

I've been reading up on WPF data binding, looking for simple examples of how to bind, say, a string, to say, a TextBlock so when the value of the string changes so does the TextBlock..

Many web examples I've found look like this . . .

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
 {
     public Window1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.DataContext = new Person { FirstName="Rowan" };
     }
 }

 public class Person
 {
     public String FirstName { get; set; }
     public String LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

... with the propertie(s) of the class being assigned in the "new" statement.   So how do I set FirstName to something else later during runtime?   Does doing a

```
this.DataContext = new Person { FirstName="Rowan" };
```

instantiate an object of type Person whose properties and methods can be accessed like any other object, the way that

```
Person a_person = new Person { FirstName="Rowan" };
```

...would?   If so, then how do I access it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recently wrote [a blog article about what exactly the `DataContext` is](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) and how its used in WPF. You may be interested in checking it out if you're just starting with WPF and are struggling to understand the `DataContext`

Comment: Yes. Although you'd have to retrieve the object instantiated in your `this.DataContext = ...` statement by casting your DataContext back to Person. For this reason, it's probably easier to create a Person object and then assign it to the DataContext, keeping the reference to the Person object as a member variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
 {
     Person GoodPerson{get;set;}
     public Window1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         GoodPerson = new Person { FirstName="Rowan" };
         this.DataContext = GoodPerson;
         GoodPerson.FirstName="Rand";
     }
 }
```

Although for your TextBlock to be notified of changes to the property your Person class will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the instance which is used as DataContext via

```
Person p = (Person)DataContext;
```